# Regex works outside C#

Tags: c#, regex, youtube

I am keen to know why a pattern is not matching in C# code while the sme executes successfully on http://gskinner.com. The pattern is:

```
^http:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtube.com\/watch\?(?=[^?]*v=\w+)(?:[^\s?]+)?$
```

I want to match

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zcKEjSYJVLs&feature=topvideos_sports
- www.youtube.com/watch?v=KsH63qJlIMM
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KsH63qJlIMM etc.

I tried in C#--

```
YoutubeVideoRegex = new Regex(@"^http:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtube.com\/watch\?(?=[^?]*v=\w+)(?:[^\s?]+)?$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

youtubeMatch = YoutubeVideoRegex.Match(url);
if (youtubeMatch.Success)
{
id = youtubeMatch.Groups[1].Value; // I want this                
}
```

But it is not matching. Any help please?`

Comment: In .NET regular expressions there is no need to escape slash (`/`) characters: they are not special (other languages, like JavaScript, use them to delimit regex literals thus they need escaping).

Comment: Thanks to the responders! When the string is http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=cQwNbSJgFbI pattern does not match while http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cQwNbSJgFbI&feature=player_detailpage, it does. Any reason why? I am not a regex guy. So pls help. I need to extract id irrespective of the position query strings

Comment: The piece of your expression `(?=[^?]*v=\w+)` ensures that the subsequent piece will only match if it starts with `v=` and is followed by a word. I suggest reviewing http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx#grouping_constructs for details on how (?=) works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to access Groups[1], but it doesn't look like your regular expression has captured any groups. Can't you just use youtubeMatch.ToString or Groups[0] to get what you're after (the whole match?) instead of trying to access sub-groups that you haven't defined?

**EDIT**

Your expression seems to work better when I remove the `?:` from the last set of parentheses. My understanding is that if your parenthesized expression starts with `?:` you are explicitly indicating that you *don't* want the expression to be captured into a group, and if it starts with `?=` you are defining a zero-width assertion, which, because it is zero-width, obviously doesn't capture anything. You need some parentheses in your expression that actually *do* capture something if you want `Groups` to be populated.

**EDIT**

Based on comments so far and some guessing at what you're trying to do, here is an updated regular expression and some updated code to demonstrate it. It works with the 2 URLs you mentioned in your comment where one would not work:

```
var re = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(
   @"^http:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtube.com\/watch\?[^?]*v=(\w+)\b[^\s?]*$",
   System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var match = re.Match(textBox1.Text);
if (match.Success)
{
   textBox2.Text = match.Value;

   if (match.Groups.Count > 1)
      textBox3.Text = match.Groups[1].Value;
   else
      textBox3.Text = "Group missing";
}
else
{
   textBox2.Text = "(No match)";
   textBox3.Text = string.Empty;
}
```

textBox2 is populated with the whole matching URL and textBox3 is populated with just the "v" query parameter.

Comment: Thanks BluemonkMN for detailed example

Answer (score 2):

i just ran your code, and it matches on your two examples with http: ->

`http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zcKEjSYJVLs&feature=topvideos_sports`
`http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KsH63qJlIMM`

but not on this one ->

`www.youtube.com/watch?v=KsH63qJlIMM`

as it obviously does not have the `http:` required by your Regex. Do you want that to be optional?

if so, just make it:

`^(http:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?youtube.com\/watch\?(?=[^?]*v=\w+)(?:[^\s?]+)?$`

and it grabs it fine